# sequences of condition checking

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new the forum so hope this question is not too elementary or that it has been asked before. While writing some code in python, I found that individual functions (here called function1, function2 and function3) returning true or false would have the same output written to screen, and therefore I would like to link them together like this;

```
if function1 or function2 or function3: 
    print "something"
```

I know that function3 will take much more time to run, so I would like to avoid it. As the condition is now written it seems to me that it would be great for me if Python first evaluates function1 to false, and then stops the evaluation of the other conditions because it knows that the if-condition is already broken. The other possibility is that the returning values of all three functions are found separately before the truth value of the combined expression is evaluated. Does anybody know the sequences of action in the if condition-evaluation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python already does this for you with a mechanism known as ["short-circuit" evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

When a Boolean expression is found to be False (for an `and`) or True (for an `or`) at any stage during the evaluation, the rest of the expression is not evaluated since the end-result is already determined at that point.

So the *order* you put things into your Boolean expression *really* matters.

This is really quite useful since you can do something like this:

```
if i != 0 and 2332.0 / i:
   ...
```

to avoid division by zero with a simple `and` expression (i.e., the division will never take place if `i` is zero).

Also, note: You do need `()` for your function calls to work.

Finally, this short-circuiting evaluation isn't unique to Python, lots of languages do this.

Comment: You should mention that as the current code is written, actually *none* of the functions is ever called.

Comment: In other words, if the first term of an `or` expression is true, the second is not evaluated; if the first term of an `and` expression is false, the second is not evaluated.

Comment: @SvenMarnach You mean because it's missing the ()

Comment: @SvenMarnach got it, I added a note.( I just took it as pseudo code initially) - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about is called "short-circuiting", and python does indeed do it.

However, I think if you want this to work properly, you want to use the `and` operator, not `or` as `False or True` returns `True` whereas `False and True` returns `False` (without ever looking at the second value).  For completeness, `True or False` returns `True` (without ever looking at `False`).

Also, In your example, you're not actually calling the functions ... to call a function in python, you need parentheses:

```
function1(args)  #for example
```

Comment: `or` will short-circuit too, it will just stop evaluating if the first term evaluates to true, since there is no need to evaluate the second.

Comment: @cdhowie -- Yes, that's true.  But it doesn't do what the OP described.

Comment: Sure, but that has nothing to do with whether or not `or` short-circuits.  I suspect that it will do what he wants, he just got one of the details incorrect when describing his problem.  Specifically, `a or b` will evaluate to the same value as `not (not a and not b)` and both will short-circuit in the exact same way -- if the `or` expression would not evaluate `b`, neither will the `and` expression.

Comment: @cdhowie -- I don't know what the OP meant ...  In any event, I updated.  It's now a little more explicit.

Comment: Sorry, I was abit to fast with my logic-operators here. It is the and-operator that I should have written, not the or. "Short-circuiting" was what I wondered about - great help, and really fast. Maybe uneccessary to revise my code, as I was interested in how python-approached my problem and not actual syntax. However, I see that it is as easy to write working code in python as none working pseudocode so I can try not been sloppy with my code if that is best for the forum.

Comment: @dexter -- I suppose one "problem" with python is that it is often difficult to distinguish it from pseudocode ;^).  Anyway, broad questions about python (such as this one) don't stay unanswered for long.